# Tengo una web con un botón que descarga un archivo .GPX, funciona bien en cualquier sistema operativo excepto en Android

Tags: html, wordpress

Lo primero gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Como pongo en el título tengo un problema con la descarga de un archivo .GPX que es un archivo que crea una ruta en cualquier aplicación de mapas, el problema que tengo es que tanto en iOS como en Windows me descarga bien el archivo con este formato pero cuando lo descargo desde un móvil con Android me añade un .txt al final lo cual hace que el archivo se "rompa" y aunque le cambies el formato ya no deja abrirlo.

¿Se os ocurre alguna manera de que no añada el .txt al final?

Os enseño el botón de descarga:

a href="https://miweb.es/wp-content/uploads/gpx/RUTA1.gpx" type="application/octet-stream" download="">Descargar</a

El octet-stream ha sido el último intento que he hecho pero sigo sin dar con la tecla.

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

he visto tu pregunta y yo estoy parecido. Cuando he ido a probar la descarga del gpx que había subido a la web solo me dejaba descargarlo en firefox y en chrome, pero si lo descargaba en safari o en el iPhone me descargaba un txt.

No sé si lo habrás solucionado ya pero, como tu problema es con los móviles, por si te sirve, a mi se me ha solucionado el tema del iPhone descargándome una aplicación para ver gpx. Nada más instalarla, he descargado el archivo y ya ha sido un gpx, no un txt. Pero en el caso de safari sigo con el problema a pesar de haberme descargado una aplicación en Mac.

Supongo que ya lo habrás probado pero espero que te sirva
Saludos

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).